# Exporting a custom made Symbol from Illustrator as a PNG for marketing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, export, png

this is my first post as a young marketeer working with Illustrator with little experience.

I am employed by a company that has never had marketing staff before. All there logos and print work are not vector based files and all need attention.

I have designed their logo in Illustrator and I want to export this as a PNG file.

I get the error message; Unable to save empty document.

The project is not empty - it contains one symbol made of 4 layers.

Any help would be amazing - thanks in advance

Comment: Please include screenshots of your screen, layers and the error message so we can see what causes the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your logo is surrounded by an Artboard.

[image]
[image]